# Unable to consume web service's values on android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services

Right now i am consuming a SOAP web service on android/eclipse.Well its working fine.Please find my service link

"http://54.251.60.177/MobileWS/Student.asmx?wsdl"

"GetStudentInformation", this is the service i am working out with and its input value is "111105009"

If i give this value as input on the above service,its just showing the result like the below images on the emulator and also showing these things publicly.

**Image_1**

[image]

**Image_2**
[image]

But here my problem is,the above image_2 is showing all the xml tags with answers,but i need to show only the answers like what i mentioned on the image_2.How to achieve this concept?

**Please find my sources below**

**WebMethod.java**

```
public class GetStudentInformation 
{
public String GetStudentInformation(String sStudentCode)
{
    return sStudentCode;
}    }
```

**Demo_tabActivity.java**

```
public class Demo_tabActivity extends Activity 
{
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "GetStudentInformation";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetStudentInformation";
private static String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/MobileWS/Student.asmx?WSDL";

Button btnFar;
EditText txtFar;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_in);
       btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
         String b;

         //Initialize soap request + add parameters
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

         //Use this to add parameters

         request.addProperty("sStudentCode",txtFar.getText().toString());

         //Declare the version of the SOAP request

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

         envelope.dotNet = true;

         try 
         {
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             //this is the actual part that will call the webservice

             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

             SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();


             if (result != null)
             {
              //Get the first property and change the label text

                b = result.toString();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Demo_tabActivity.this, Tabhost.class);

                myIntent.putExtra("result1", b);
                startActivity(myIntent);
             }
             else
             {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
       });
   }
}
```

**Tabhost.java**

```
public class Tabhost extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    String result1;

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras!=null)
    {
        result1 = extras.getString("result1");
    } else result1 = "Didnt work !" ;



    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab_1.class);
    intent.putExtra("result1", result1);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab_2.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
 }
 }
```

**Tab_1.java**

```
public class Tab_1 extends Activity 
{
TextView tv1;
String result1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{   
    result1 = extras.getString("result1");
} 
else result1 = "didnt work";

    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_main2);
    tv1.setText(result1);


}
}
```

**Tab_2.java**

```
public class Tab_2 extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main3);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your precious help!...

Comment: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example this link contains the example of android xml SAX parser. It might be helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web service is returning you a response in `xml` format. You simply need to parse it and get the needed information out. There are many of example on the internet explaining how to do that.

https://www.google.com/search?q=android+xml+parsing+example